# Working code throwing exception when new lines added. Debugging tips?

Tags: c++, debugging, shared-libraries, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm working on a proprietary code base, so I have to abstract this.

I'm trying to set the value of DataType_T*** myData in MyApplication. I'm using a shared c++ library (which I denote library A) to set the value. The shared c++ library is just a simple wrapper class around a C API.The C API is included in library A as a shared library (which I denote library B).

So MyApplication calls GetData(myData) in A which calls GetData(myData) in B.

MyApplication has the following code:

```
void OnButtonPress(){
    const DataType*** myData;
    GetData(myData);
    DataTypeVal1 val1 = (*myData)[0]->val1; // just grabbing some info.
}
```

> GetData(myData): works, and properly sets myData.
>
> Me: types some new code

```
void OnButtonPress(){
    const DataType*** myData;
    GetData(myData);
    const void* strData = (*myData)[0]->strData; // just grabbing some info now that we have the pointer.

    //Add lots more new code that does this over and over for each member of myData
    String^ str = gcnew String(static_cast<const char*>(strData));
}
```

> GetData(myData): throws a write access violation.
>
> Me: ".   .   .   .   .   .   .what."

- Could the exception be getting thrown because of some sort of dll unloading?
- Is there a possibility that the linking process changes when I type new code?

I haven't encountered an issue like this before, so I don't really know how to debug this.

Got suggestions?

Thanks.

---

Solved. 
I found my undefined behavior.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say this is Undefined Behavior. You're messing with triple pointers and `void*`, so it wouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: I know that the C library is unit tested to death, and the wrapper I wrote myself, but it is literally just passing variables to the C lib calls, so I would be led to believe that any undefined behavior could only come from the application layer, but what I've written as example is pretty close to the sparseness of the real application. I'll keep looking though.

Comment: Found it. Thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
const DataType** myData;
GetData(&myData);
const void* strData = myData[0]->strData;
```

Because in the original code you're just passing a pointer by value; an uninitialized pointer, and then accessing that same uninitialized value.

ed: fixed up the third line

Comment: Mostly true. Doing it your way, you wouldn't want to dereference myData on the third line. However, this did end up simplifying my usage and help me find my bug. So I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks